# При удалении продукта, удалить так же его из закладок, и его лайки

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица продуктов

```
CREATE TABLE products(
    product_id                          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    product_name                        VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    product_description                 VARCHAR(220) NOT NULL, 
    ...
)
```

Таблица закладок:

```
CREATE TABLE bookmarks_products(
    bookmark_id                        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    product_id                         INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES products, 
    user_id                            INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users
);
```

Таблица лайков:

```
CREATE TABLE likes_products(
    like_id                            SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    product_id                         INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES products, 
    user_id                            INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users
);
```

Таблица комментариев:

```
CREATE TABLE comments(
    comment_id                         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    user_id                            INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users, 
    product_id                         INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES products,
    parent_id                          INTEGER,,
    user_name                          VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

Я делаю удаление например продукта номер 1:

```
DELETE FROM COMMENTS WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 1;
```

При создании таблиц я создал вторичные ключи у таблиц (лайки, закладки, комментарии).

Как мне удалить продукт номер 1 из таблицы продуты, и так же удалить из всех таблиц (лайки, закладки, комментарии)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте конструкцию `ON DELETE CASCADE` при объявлении внешнего ключа. Тогда ваша СУБД будет автоматически удалять дочерние записи из так привязанных таблиц.

Пример создания таблицы с комментариями:

```
CREATE TABLE comments(
    comment_id     SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    user_id        INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users, 
    product_id     INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES products ON DELETE CASCADE,
    parent_id      INTEGER,
    user_name      VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

подробнее в [документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/ddl-constraints.html)

Answer (score 3):

Настроить каскадное удаление записей, либо удалять "руками" - сначала все дочерние записи, а потом основную